# Unit Testing libraries for blackberry

Tags: java, unit-testing, blackberry, shared-libraries

I'm developing a library for a BB 5.0 app, however I don't know how to test this library without including it in a Application project.

Is there a way of unit testing the code in my blackberry library, it doesn't use any Ui elements.

Comment: What would you be trying out, if there isn't an application?

Comment: @MichaelDonohue I've just edited my question